# AutoSuggestBox Async search

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there anyway to have an awaitable search inside the TextChanged method

```
private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
        {
            Async Search ????!!!! 
            sender.ItemsSource = dataset;
        }
    }
```

For example search in ContactStore to show matching emails, names, ...

Comment: I think your question it's not clear... what are you trying to achieve?
If you want to search for contacts you can just call
`var list = await ContactStore.FindContactAsync();`

Then iterate/filter your list based on your needs and assign the result to the sender.ItemsSource. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write an await statement, you need to make the method async like

```
    private async Task AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged()
    {
         await task1();
    }
```